# Can you make an XSLT group by itself through lookup?

Tags: xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part, grouping

Recently I figured out this nice grouping template that I will paste below. Now I am wondering:

my list is really simple:

Title

Parent (= lookup to Title of this list)

I would like to this list to group like this:
In an easy to understand example, this would be the output:

- grandpa
  - mom
    - me
    - brother
    - sister
      - niece
      - nephew
  - aunt
    - cousin
    - cousin
  - uncle
    - cousin
    - cousin
    - cousin
      - child

I thought looking up to itself was called 'recursive', but apperantly it's not what I'm looking for on the internet. Is there a proper term for this?

I've spent quite some time looking around and trying stuff out, I'm wondering if it's at all possible

Below is my group by two column template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="header1" match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" use="@Group1"/>
<xsl:key name="header2" match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" use="concat(@Group1, '|', @Group2)"/>
<xsl:key name="item" match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" use="concat(@Group1, '|', @Group2, '|', @Title)"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('header1', @Group1)[1])]" mode="header1"/>
</xsl:template>
<!-- header1 -->
<xsl:template match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" mode="header1">
<H1><xsl:value-of select="@Group1"/></H1>
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('header1', @Group1)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('header2', concat(@Group1, '|', @Group2))[1])]" mode="header2"/>
</xsl:template>
<!-- header2 -->
<xsl:template match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" mode="header2">
<h2><xsl:value-of select="@Group2"/></h2>
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('header2', concat(@Group1, '|', @Group2))[generate-id() = generate-id(key('item', concat(@Group1, '|', @Group2, '|', @Title))[1])]" mode="item"/>
</xsl:template>
<!-- items -->
<xsl:template match="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row" mode="item">
<xsl:value-of select="@Title"/><br/>  
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You mean 3rd level grouping is not working? Your issue is not clear from question

Comment: Thanks Amal, you replied quickly while I was cleaning up the code in my post!
 

Basically I would like to build a looping structure to create an unlimited number of subgroups. For each new item you create you can select one of the existing items as 'parent' through the lookup column

Comment: each items consist simply of [title] and [parent]  ,  using these items I am looking to recreate the family  tree in my post above

Comment: Can this be done? I appreciate any input!